# Midnight Commander user menu command to run external diff tool

Tags: midnight-commander, meld, difftool

Is it possible to create an entry in Midnight Commander's "user menu", which operates on two files, possibly one from each pane?

I'm trying to set up a user command that will open Meld for diffing two files (instead of the built-in differ). But I can't figure out how to operate on two files at once.

Comment: http://www.softpanorama.org/OFM/MC/user_menu.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+ ! t t
-   meld diff, current files (or dirs) from two panels
    meld %f %F

+ t t
-   meld diff, tagged files (or dirs) from one panel
    meld %t
```

For better understanding see `man mc` (section *Edit Menu File* and *Macro Substitution*) or try [this mc menu](https://github.com/musinsky/config/tree/master/MidnightCommander) with *view Midnight Commander macro substitution (debug)* entry (at the end of the mc menu file).

Comment: Thanks, I almost have it working. If I select two files in one pane, it shows the "from one pane" option. But if I select one file in each pane, the "from two panels" option doesn't show. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, `+ t t` and `+ ! t t` are addition conditions (`+ t t` = show menu entry only if tagged file). Try simple remove (or comment with `#`) this conditions.

Comment: `%f` = current file, `%t` = tagged files. If letter is in uppercase %F or %T refers to the other (unselected, opposite) panel. You can try `meld %t %T`. Please see `man mc` or github example in the post above.

Comment: Ah my mistake was I was selecting (INS) the files in each panel. When I just highlight each one, the "two panel" option works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. For ubuntu 22 it works for me like this in the file ~/.config/mc/menu


      meld %d/%f %D/%F


%d and %D are the directory names. Without it meld opened the same file twice.